# Testing a constructor that contains asynchronous code

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to test a constructor in node.js that uses asynchronous code, to test out a feature in it. I know the asynchronous code works because I have already ran it, before I put in the feature, as if I were an end-user. [In fact, I got it thanks to some user who answered another question I had](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38673768/functions-not-being-reached)

**The feature**

The `User` constructor has a `userRole` member, and some async code that checks `userType` specified against `User.userTypes`. If `userType` found, `this.userRole` is set to `userType`. Else, exception is thrown.

The code looks like this:

```
async.forEachSeries(
    User.userTypes,
    function(user_type, callback)
    {
        if (user_type == userType)
        {
            this.userRole = user_type;
            return;
        }
        if (user_type == User.userTypes[User.userTypes.length - 1])
        {
            callback(helpers.invalidData("user_role"));
            return;
        }
        callback(null);
    },
    function(err)
    {
        if (err)
        {
            if (DEBUG)
            {
                console.log("Error from constructor...");
                console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, '\t') + "\n");
            }
            throw err;
        }
    }
);
```

The rest of the constructor looks like:

```
function User(id, email, displayName, password, userType, deleted, cb)
{
    var DEBUG = true;
    var error = null;
    this.userID = id;
    this.email = email;
    this.displayName = displayName;
    this.deleted = deleted;
    var self = this;
    async.forEachSeries(
        User.userTypes,
        function(user_type, callback)
        {
            if (user_type == userType)
            {
                this.userRole = user_type;
                return;
            }
            if (user_type == User.userTypes[User.userTypes.length - 1])
            {
                callback(helpers.invalidData("user_role"));
                return;
            }
            callback(null);
        },
        function(err)
        {
            if (err)
            {
                if (DEBUG)
                {
                    console.log("Error from constructor...");
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, '\t') + "\n");
                }
                throw err;
            }
        }
    );
    if (User.connectedToDatabase) this._password = password;
    else
    {
        bcrypt.genSalt(10, function (e, salt) {
            bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function (e, hash) {
                if (!e)
                {
                    self._password = hash;
                    if (DEBUG)
                    {
                        console.log("this._password ==" + self._password);
                        console.log("this.userID == " + self.userID);
                    }
                    if (typeof cb === 'function')
                        cb(null, this);

                }
                else
                {
                    console.log("Error occurred: ");
                    console.log(e);
                    if (typeof cb === 'function')
                        cb(e);
                }
            })
        });
    }
}

User.connectedToDatabase = false;
User.BASIC = "basic user";
User.INVENTORY_MANAGEMENT = "inventory";
User.ADMIN = "admin";
User.userTypes = [ User.BASIC, User.INVENTORY_MANAGEMENT, User.ADMIN ];

User.prototype.userID = 0;
User.prototype.email = null;
User.prototype.displayName = null;
User.prototype._password = null;
User.prototype.userRole = User.BASIC;
User.prototype.deleted = false;

User.prototype.responseObject = function() {
    return {
        id: this.userID,
        email: this.email,
        displayName: this.displayName,
        userType: this.userRole
    };
}
```

**My test**

I write `test()` function that takes parameters to pass to `User`. If `User` constructed without error, it, along with some of its members are printed to console. Else, error is printed. Here is code:

```
function test(email, name, pass, type)
{
    try
    {
        var a = new User(Math.round(Math.random() * 32),
            email, 
            name, 
            pass, 
            type
        );
        console.log("Test user created: " + JSON.stringify(a.responseObject(), null, '\t') + "\n");
        console.log("User._password == " + a._password);
        console.log("\n");
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        console.log("User could not be created.\n" + JSON.stringify(e, null, '\t') + "\n");
    }
    /*async.waterfall([
        function(callback){
            var a = new User(Math.round(Math.random * 32),
                email,
                name,
                pass, 
                type);
            callback(null, a);
        },
        function(a, callback) {
            console.log("Test user created: " + JSON.stringify(a, null, '\t') + "\n");
            console.log("User._password == " + a._password);
            console.log("User.userID == " + a.userID);
            console.log("\n");
            callback(null, a);
        }
    ],
    function(err, results)
    {
        console.log("results of test: " + JSON.stringify(results, null, '\t'));
        if (err)
        {
            console.log("User could not be created.\n" + JSON.stringify(err, null, '\t') + "\n");

        }
    })*/

}
```

My test cases are as follows:

1. userType matching first element of `User.userTypes`
2. userType matching another element of `User.userTypes` (I picked the last one)
3. userType not matching any of `User.userTypes`

At runtime, after new User created, `User._password` is default value and not the value my asynchronous code comes up with for it.[image: Sample run] I suspect I have some async-sync error, but haven't been able to fix it.

Comment: **Don't make complex constructors**. It's just asking for (so much) trouble, since you're putting a lot of code into a function the runtime has to call occasionally. If you have a ton of extra work to do, put it in an `init` method of some sort and call that later.

Comment: @ssube As in call from constructor, or from code that calls constructor? asynchronously or synchronously?

Comment: Code in (or called from) the constructor itself. A constructor should take parameters and tuck them away for future requests, but it shouldn't go out over the network and perform a bunch of asynchronous work that could potentially fail later. That is, a constructor does not have a way to indicate failure without throwing, so it should never rely on anything that could fail later. If it does, you can have a partially-constructed object, which is essentially undefined behavior (the worst thing we know of).

Comment: Doing too much in the constructor is also the most common cause of chicken-and-egg problems (circular dependencies). Doing the heavy, deferred initialization later typically solves that.

Comment: Can you give example? I am new to this whole async vs. sync concept....

Comment: Consider a file reader that takes a path and opens a file. Checking that the path is valid and turning it into a canonical path (getting rid of `..` segments) is quick, well-defined, and synchronous. Doing that in the constructor is a-ok. Opening the file and reading it should probably live elsewhere, because it's complex, may not finish, is asynchronous, and prone to failure.

Comment: If you'd like to continue talking about this, [let's move it to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17)? I'd be happy to explain some of the differences and why I think constructors should be kept simple.

Comment: [Do not write asynchronous constructors!](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24398699/1048572)

Comment: Actually your code does not work. You'd have to use  `self` instead of `this` in the callback.

Comment: @ssube: Actually it's not so much about async vs sync, it's about side effects vs. pure computations. A constructor should not affect global state. (It's just that asynchronous functions are typically doing these complex bad things)

Comment: @Bergi I fixed it, and now it works. However, I should probably move my async stuff to a method (be that a member of `User` or a method that exists elsewhere). Once I get `connectedToDatabase`, that async stuff won't happen....

Answer (score 0):

Got it fixed, thanks to @Bergi's advice.

First thing I did: in that `async.forEachSeries()`, I changed any instance of `this` to `self`.

Second thing I did: replaced that asynchronous code (that was working!) to synchronous code. Instead of this:

```
bcrypt.genSalt(10, function (e, salt) {
        bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function (e, hash) {
            if (!e)
            {
                self._password = hash;
                if (DEBUG)
                {
                    console.log("this._password ==" + self._password);
                    console.log("this.userID == " + self.userID);
                }
                if (typeof cb === 'function')
                    cb(null, this);

            }
            else
            {
                console.log("Error occurred: ");
                console.log(e);
                if (typeof cb === 'function')
                    cb(e);
            }
        })
    });
```

I simply said: `this._password = bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(10));` and all was good!